# How to restart program after interruption?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I start my program again after interruption and kill the previous process? What I have to write in my function? Or maybe another way to restart program in itself exists?

`this_program.sh`:

```
trap 'mySig' SIGINT
mySig()
{
        ./this_program.sh
}
```

Comment: Please define "interruption" to get more exact answers.

Comment: My bad. Termination signal. In this case -- ctrl+C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the signal handler, you should:

- make sure you separate the new process from the running one and
- actually terminate the running process in the signal handler

Example:

```
trap 'mySig' SIGINT
mySig()
{
        ./this_program.sh & disown
        kill $$
}
```

You could also run your program from a wrapper process:

```
while true
do
    ./this_program.sh
done
```